# How to make a recovery disk combining the OS and the applications?

Tags: backup-restoration

To avoid doing tedious job by reinstalling the OS every 6 months, I want to create a recovery disk that combines the OS and required applications.

So I can install the complete system only by one-click installation.

This is just for educational purpose rather than for making money.

Comment: Honest question...is this allowed under licensing for a trial edition?

Comment: @Bart: please see my update.

Comment: Right, this site is for pro sysadmins not students, that restore trick won't work because the 180 days starts from install date and is stamped all over the place so you don't hack it

Comment: Done, I'll delete these user name comments in a moment but you can't do what you want with that 180 days thing, you just can't ok.

Answer (score 2):

Even if it works it would be breaking the license agreement. I'm a moderator here and this site is for professional sysadmins, I'm of the opinion that consciously breaking licensing agreements for financial gain is both unprofessional and immoral., so I would strongly recommend you do not do this.

Answer (score 0):

I say give it a try, but I bet it won't work. If you do a complete restore, it seems that it is going to also restore whatever files/registry settings it is using to keep track of your 180 day trial.